# Bulk loading data into MarkLogic via external RESTful services

Tags: json, rest, marklogic

I have series of documents that I need to migrate into MarkLogic. The documents are available to me via RESTful services in JSON. What I want to know is there anyway, such as through the MLCP or Query Console to call those RESTful services and pull in the data, otherwise I have to create a small Java app and dump the files to a share then pick them up from MarkLogic.

Answer (score 5):

[mlcp](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump) is designed to source data from the file system or a MarkLogic database. Take a look at the [Java Client API](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/) to perform ingestion from other sources. For example, you can fire up your favorite HTTP client in Java and add the results to a [`DocumentWriteSet`](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentWriteSet.html). The write set acts like a buffer, allowing you to batch requests to MarkLogic for efficiency. You can then send that `DocumentWriteSet` to MarkLogic with one of the [`DocumentManager.write()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentManager.html#write(com.marklogic.client.document.DocumentWriteSet)) methods. Take a look at the [documentation for many more details](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/bulk#id_27479) or the "Bulk Writes" section of the [getting started cookbook](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/java-client-api-2).

Comment: Or if you want to leverage MLCP's bulk loading capabilities, you can probably use camel to pull data from source then save to file system.